# useWeb3React hook doesn't return provider

Tags: reactjs, web3js, web3-react

I want to access the Ethereum blockchain through [Cloudflare Ethereum Gateway](https://developers.cloudflare.com/distributed-web/ethereum-gateway/interacting-with-the-eth-gateway). I am trying to use [web3-react](https://github.com/NoahZinsmeister/web3-react) library, but `useWeb3React` doesn't return object with `provider` property.

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-cdn-7nbsm?file=/src/App.js:126-138)

**index.js**

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Web3 from "web3";
import { Web3ReactProvider } from "@web3-react/core";

import App from "./App";

function getLibrary(provider) {
  const web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
    "https://cloudflare-eth.com"
  );
  const web3 = new Web3(web3Provider);
  return web3;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Web3ReactProvider getLibrary={getLibrary}>
      <App />
    </Web3ReactProvider>
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

**App.js**

```
import { useWeb3React } from "@web3-react/core";

import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const web3React = useWeb3React();
  console.log({ web3React });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue in the library describing this exact problem with the solution here: https://github.com/NoahZinsmeister/web3-react/issues/126#issuecomment-783057749

Seems like you have to call `web3React.activate()` in your App.js with whatever connector you want to use. So for example with the [@web3-react/injected-connector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@web3-react/injected-connector):

```
import { useWeb3React } from "@web3-react/core";
import { InjectedConnector } from "@web3-react/injected-connector";

import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const web3React = useWeb3React();

  web3React.activate(new InjectedConnector({
    supportedChainIds: [1, 3, 4, 5, 42]
  }));
  console.log({ web3React });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks David, this is helpful, but when I import `InjectedConnector`, the project doesn't compile. I get error `node_modules/@web3-react/abstract-connector/dist/abstract-connector.esm.js:1:9: error: No matching export in "browser-external:events" for import "EventEmitter"` complete messsage [here](https://imgur.com/a/1l9iykN)

Comment: Sure thing matt, glad if I am able to help.
Did you `npm install @web3-react/injected-connector` before?

Comment: Yes, I installed the npm package. If better answer won't pop up, I will award your answer.

Comment: okay. nut sure if it helps, but in the linked GitHub issue, they actually call activate like this: `web3.activate(injected, undefined, true);` where injected is defined outside like `const injected = new InjectedConnector({
  supportedChainIds: [1, 3, 4, 5, 42],
});`. Maybe that'll work? (so the difference are the two additional arguments `undefined` and `true`)

Comment: Thanks, I tried it out but it didn't help. I am using Vite instead of CRA. I will try it out with CRA later and let you know.

Comment: I just tried it out in CRA and now I am getting error: `NoEthereumProviderError: No Ethereum provider was found on window.ethereum.`

Comment: The code snippet is for using MetaMask, but I would like to connect through  Cloudflare Ethereum Gateway

Comment: I figured this out, I need to use `NetworkConnector` instead of `InjectedConnector`. I will award your answer tomorrow.